# Реализация контактной книги с проверкой базы контактов

Tags: mobile-development, мобильные-приложения, контакты

Столкнулся с проблемой реалзиции контактной книги в мобильном приложении, где при открытии контроллера происходит получение контактов из контактной книги и после, те контакты, которые зарегистрированы в приложении (находятся на сервере приложения), как-то отмечаются. Например, в приложении Сбербанк или других банковских приложениях в контактах отмечаются клиенты данного банка. Подскажите реализацию этого функционала. Постоянно получать список контактов с сервера будет неверным решением, отправлять все контакты на сервер, думаю, тоже..

Comment: У Васи есть список А, у Пети - список Б. Как им найти пересечения по списку, если Вася не хочет показывать свой список Пете, а Петя - Васе? Что-то куда-то отправлять придётся. Не хотите это делать "постоянно" - делайте с регулярностью, которую считаете достаточной. Да и вопрос, в целом, философский какой-то.

Answer (score 1):

Получать список всех контактов с сервера не безопасно. Остаётся только отправить контакты на сервер. Это не такая уж и большая проблема, даже если у вас 1000 контактов, то их номера телефонов будут весить всего ~10КБ. Отправьте один раз, сохраните ответ в кэш и обновляйте при изменении контактов либо по времени

Answer (score 1):

Как реализовал бы я.

1. Получаем список контактов в мобильном приложении.
2. [Кодируем](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) каждый контакт в hash-строку (например, с [солью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)))
3. Заносим в БД приложения список контактов и hash-строки
4. Отправляем массив на сервер
5. На сервере имеющиеся контакты кодируем аналогично (например, с [солью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F))) в hash-сткроки.
6. Сравниваем hash-строки пользователя и hash-строки на сервере
7. Выводим пересечение и возвращаем пользователю
8. Сравниваем пересечение с данными в БД приложения